# SQL Multiply current and all previous row columns

Tags: sql

Using Postgres, I'd like to learn how to multiply the current value by all previous values. For example, the total of the 4th value would be 4*3*2*1.

Input:

```
Value: 1
Value: 2
Value: 3
Value: 4
```

Output:

```
Total: 0
Total: 2
Total: 6
Total: 24
```

Comment: I assume your first total is 0 because it's null*null, and you're using isnull([yourFutureCalculatedValue],0)?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a table named `numbers` with a column named `n`. You could do the following:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE mul(bigint) ( SFUNC = int8mul, STYPE=bigint );

SELECT mul(n) OVER (ORDER BY m.row_num) FROM (
    SELECT n, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY n) from numbers
) m;
```

Postgres doesn't have an aggregation function for multiplication, so we need to make one first. Then we use it in the second query.

Comment: @Elliott, Sorry but I don't understand.

Comment: @AndrewCPKelley Fleshed out my answer a bit more. Hope that helps.

Comment: @elliott - Why do the row numbers come into play? I was thinking something more like exp(sum(log(sub_total) over (order by date))

Comment: @AndrewCPKelley They don't necessarily have to come into play, I was just trying to come up with a generic solution that would work no matter what your dataset looks like.